# How to write a view of a user signed up nodes?

Tags: 7, views, users

There is a content-type (event) with signup enabled. I want to show, on a user profile, the events this user has already signed up. I am having several frustrations with the signup relations and arguments. Is this possible with the current 2.x release?

Comment: is this using a contrib event signup module or some custom code?

Comment: As barraponto is referring to the "current 2.x release," I think he is not referring to a custom module. @barraponto Can you provide the link to the project page? Without to know to which module you are referring, users cannot answer correctly, or without making any guess.

Comment: I am referring to http://drupal.org/project/signup

Comment: That project doesn't seem to have a 2.x release, does it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno it seems it hasn't been released, i got it from git. any way, i reverted to 1.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default view called signup_current_signups that provides this functionality out of the box.